# Change Play2 JavaGlobal's location

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGlobal But it requires the Global object to be placed at root package, which looks very ugly, how can I change it to another package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `application.conf` file you can specify your Global's location.

```
application.global=yourpackage.Global
```